# Is it possible to redefine the & aligment symbol?

Tags: matrices

In constructs such as `{matrix}` and when aligning multi-line equations, you use the ampersand `&` as alignment symbol. Is it possible to use another symbol for that?
(There are reasons for my question... :) )

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Consider registering to the site, so you will be able to participate fully. Can you briefly explain the reasons? There may be several ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The alignment tab, while associated, by default, with `&`, is really whatever character is associated with the catcode 4 (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/catcode).  Thus, if something else is assigned a `\catcode` of 4, it (also) becomes an alignment tab.

In the MWE below, I not only make `@` an alignment tab, but I unmake `&` an alignment tab and instead make it an "other" type character, which will display in normal text.

Of course, one must be careful, that the reassignment does not break other things in the process.  In the MWE, I perform the reassignments inside the `\[...\]` environment, and thus the tabbing character reverts to the `&` upon leaving the environment and `@` reverts to an "other" type character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12}\\
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\[
\catcode`@=4 %
\catcode`&=12 %
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} @ A_{12}\\
A_{21} @ &_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\]
@@
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was quick! I will see if I can make this work.

Comment: @NielsFanøe See revision for more details.